# How to load and read JKS file with Bouncy Castle using C#

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, jks

I'd like to sign `PDF` with a `private key` which is stored in `JKS` file.
I have to load this JKS using `C#` and `BouncyCastle`, but I can't find any example even where I could start from.

I need something like this

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("AppTest.jks");
ks.load(is, "AppTest".toCharArray());
is.close();
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(user, password.toCharArray());
```

Comment: Is the keystore in JKS format? If so, are you able to change it to say PKCS12?

Comment: Yes, keystore is in JKS format. But I can't change it. I need to get private key directly from this file with BouncyCastle to sign my PDF file.

Comment: @VitaliiChuzha Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: hi @VitaliiChuzha, with a quick test I can get it to read from a PKCS12 keystore, but not JKS keystore.